# Can i use Whatsapp business API directly to create a ChatBot?

Tags: facebook, chatbot, whatsapp

I would like to implement a standalone ChatBot, i.e., the ChatBot is the product (for entertainment) , and it is not meant to perform customer service for any real business.

I'm in the process of creating such a ChatBot, but WhatsApp disabled my business (during the business review process, before I made any API calls) with the following statement:

> This account has been disabled because the website listed in its Business Manager profile does not provide the information needed to determine if your business complies with our Business Policy.

I'm quite confident that my website accurately describes what I'm trying to achieve. My question is whether this use case (creating a ChatBot) is considered legitimate?